# SQL LEFT JOIN with GROUP BY, COUNT & WHERE clause (VBA)

Tags: sql, vba, excel, adodb

> Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications
>   -
>   SQL LEFT JOIN with GROUP BY, COUNT & WHERE clause

Issue solved: Thanks for sharing the link @Vityata. Given below is the corrected code for others to refer to.

```
strSQL = "SELECT A.ID, A.Reason, COUNT(B.TimeStamp)" & _
"FROM tblReasons A " & _
"Left Join " & _
"(" & _
"SELECT TimeStamp, Reason FROM tblTracker " & _
"WHERE TimeStamp > #04/11/2017# and TimeStamp < #04/14/2017# " & _
")B ON A.ID = B.Reason " & _
" GROUP BY A.ID, A.Reason"
```

Comment: To the best of my knowledge the WHERE clause should be after the LEFT JOIN clause.

Comment: @Rory you are right about that. I do not get the error anymore but I am not getting the desired results either. I am unable to make JOIN and WHERE clause to work. I am trying to get the count of all tblReasons.Reason irrespective if WHERE returns any tblTracker.TimeStamp. So it should display 0 count if no results found with WHERE clause

Comment: Its much easier, if you start with getting the right SQL-syntax within Access. If erverything works in Access and you get the desired result, copy the sql to Excel-VBA ant put it within you code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following.

1. Go to the immediate window in VBE. (ctrl + G). Then paste the strSQL and press enter on each line. *(see the picture below)*
2. Then ask VBE what does it understand by the whole thing, by writing `?strsql` and press enter. *(see the picture below)*
3. VBE would answer. Inspect the answer.
4. Put the answer as a query in Access.
5. Research & find the problem.

[image]

In general, I think that GROUP BY and LEFT JOIN are a bit wrong, but I should see the data to tell you more. [SQL - Group By with Left Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231909/sql-group-by-with-left-join)

Comment: Try to put `HAVING` after the `GROUP BY` instead of the `WHERE`. And play a bit.

Comment: Another thought - check the dates. E.g. 04/11 - is it 4.November or something fake? Try writing `#11/04/2017# and #12/04/2017#`, it may work.

Comment: Just try a simple query with the table, just `select * from table where tblTracker.Timestamp between #04/11/2017# and #04/12/2017` And try to optimize it from there.

Comment: For the syntax error, probably put some brackets around something and try again ...`[ ]`

Comment: SELECT tblReasons.ID, tblReasons.Reason, COUNT(tblTracker.Reason) FROM tblReasons LEFT JOIN tblTracker ON tblReasons.ID = tblTracker.Reason WHERE tblTracker.Timestamp between #04/08/2017# AND #04/09/2017# GROUP BY tblReasons.ID, tblReasons.Reason ORDER BY COUNT(tblTracker.Reason) DESC this works with no errors but does not give the desired results. I wish to retrieve tblReasons.ID, tblReasons.Reason irrespective of data in tblTracker. I thought LEFT JOIN is supposed to do that.